# How to State management of many data depths ?? plz help me

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

In this json object, I want to add and change the values ​​of the list called "m" while traversing the array called "j". What should I do ??

```
   {
    "a": "string",
    "h": false,
        "i": "string",
    "j": [
        {
            "k": 0,
            "l": "NONE",
            "m": [
                {
                    "n": "string",
                    "o": []
                }
            ],
            "p": [],
            "q": [],

        }
    ],
    "r": [
        {
            "s": "string",
            "t": "strin",
            "u": "string",
            "v": null,

        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? It should be easy enough to find questions on this site relating to accessing certain properties of an object or iterating through an array.

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, you'd do something like this:

```
let obj = JSON.parse(json_data);
for(let key in obj.j){
    if(key=='m'){
         //if you want to skip 'm'
         continue;
    }
    let value = obj.j[key];
    //do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**This is the way to traverse and modify the array and its elements.**

```js
let response={
    "a": "string",
    "h": false,
        "i": "string",
    "j": [
        {
            "k": 0,
            "l": "NONE",
            "m": [
                {
                    "n": "string",
                    "o": []
                }
            ],
            "p": [],
            "q": [],

        }
    ],
    "r": [
        {
            "s": "string",
            "t": "strin",
            "u": "string",
            "v": null,

        }
    ]
}

let newObject=response.j.map(ele=>
{ele.m.map(el=>{el.n="IamChanged",el.myName="IamChanged"})}

)

console.log(response);
```

What do you want in output??